# Create EventHandler and listen to Event from another class

Tags: c#

I've created event as bellow and want to listen to it and execute method in another class when it fires 
but saveEvent always comes to be null and it doesn't fire 
I don't know what I've missed

here's my first class has button

```
internal partial class OpenSaveReportWizardForm : Form
{
public event EventHandler saveEvent;
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  saveEvent?.Invoke(this, e); 
}
}
```

and here's the second class where I want to listen to saveEvent

```
 internal class Database
 {
  public Database()
  { 
        Program._wizardForm.saveEvent += (sender, e) => HandleSaveMethod( );

  }

public void HandleSaveMethod()
  {
   // do something
  }
```

here's where I open the form

```
internal  class Program
{
  public static OpenSaveReportWizardForm _wizardForm;
  private static void Main()
  {
  OpenFileCommandHandler();
  }

void OpenFileCommandHandler()
     { 
        _wizardForm = new OpenSaveReportWizardForm( );

        _wizardForm.ShowDialog(); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: because as soon as the using block exits the saveEvent property is cleared as form gets disposed

Comment: when I use debugger on saveButton_Click saveEvent will be null there 
so saveEvent doesn't fire eventually

Comment: based on the fact that you don't even `Show` the form, I'm making a guess that you are opening the form elsewhere in your program but expecting it to be the same instance as what you create in your `Database` class. Even if you fix your code so it does not `Dispose` immediately, you won't get the result you want unless you reference the same instance that is open.

Comment: i think you right cause i open the form from another class different than both mentioned above so shall I get ref from that instance and use it in Db class

Answer (score 0):

Because you disposed wizardForm, after that event is cleared.
You should write next code:

```
 internal class Database
 {
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private OpenSaveReportWizardForm _wizardForm;

  public Database()
  {
      _wizardForm = new  OpenSaveReportWizardForm(m_Opening,m_ConnectionProperties,m_ColumnProperties))
      _wizardForm.saveEvent += (sender, e) => HandleSaveMethod( );

  }

public void HandleSaveMethod()
  {
   // do something
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    if(_isDisposed)
        return;

    _isDisposed = true;

    _wizardForm.saveEvent -= HandleSaveMethod;
    _wizardForm.Dispose();
  }
```

Comment: the compiler doesn't reach Db class cause on click event saveEvent is null